# RabbitMq is delivering messages but not creating queue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-exchange

as explained in the title, I am using spring boot to send a message and receive it, apparently, it is working perfectly since I can see what I send in the console:

Sending a message:

[sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBVDy.png)

Receiving a message:

[receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJTqr.png)

The problem here is that I can't see my message in RabbitMq interface and the queue is not even created :
[RabbitMq Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Q8n.png)

This is my **RabbitMqConfig**

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {


@Value("MessageQueue")
private String qName;


@Value("exchange")
private String exchange;


@Value("routekey")
private String routingKey;

@Bean
Queue qu() {
    return new Queue(qName, Boolean.FALSE);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange topicExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(exchange);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(final Queue q, final TopicExchange topicExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(topicExchange).with(routingKey);
}

@Bean(name = "pimAmqpAdmin")
public AmqpAdmin pimAmqpAdmin( ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
}

}
```

This is my **sender**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
@RestController
public class Sender {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Sender.class);


@Autowired
RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
@Autowired
Binding binding;

@GetMapping(value = "/send/{msg}")
@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
public String send(@PathVariable("msg") final String message) {
    LOGGER.info("Sending message to the queue.");
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(binding.getExchange(), binding.getRoutingKey(), message);
    LOGGER.info("Message sent successfully to the queue!!!");
    return "Great!! your message is sent";
}
}
```

and this is my **Receiver**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Receiver {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

@Autowired
Queue qu;

@RabbitListener(queues = "#{qu.getName()}")
public void getMsg(final String message) {
    LOGGER.info("Getting messages.....");
    LOGGER.info("Finally Receiver received the message and the message  is..\n" + message);
}
}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default guest user? if yes, try to create a new user with a username and password and use it instead of a guest.